# jQuery: Selecting by class and input type

Tags: jquery

I would like to select a set of elements that are both of a certain input type (say, a checkbox) and have a certain class using jQuery.  However, when I try the following:

```
 $("input:checkbox .myClass")
```

I don't get any items returned.  How can I accomplish this in jQuery?

Answer (score 235, accepted):

Your selector is looking for any descendants of a checkbox element that have a class of `.myClass`.

Try this instead:

```
$("input.myClass:checkbox")
```

[Check it out in action](http://jsbin.com/uyutu).

I also tested this:

```
$("input:checkbox.myClass")
```

And it will also work properly. In my humble opinion this syntax really looks rather ugly, as most of the time I expect `:` style selectors to come last. As I said, though, either one will work.

Answer (score 62):

If you want to get the inputs of that type with that class use:

```
$("input.myClass[type=checkbox]")
```

the [] selector syntax allows you to check against any of the elements attributes.
Check out the [spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/selector.html#matching-attrs) for more details

Answer (score 7):

You have to use (for checkboxes) `:checkbox` and the `.name` attribute to select by class.

For example:

```
$("input.aclass:checkbox")
```

The `:checkbox` selector:

> Matches all input elements of type checkbox. Using this
>   psuedo-selector like `$(':checkbox')` is equivalent to `$('*:checkbox')`
>   which is a slow selector. 
>   It's recommended to do `$('input:checkbox')`.

You should read [jQuery documentation](http://docs.jquery.com/Selectors) to know about selectors.

Answer (score 6):

You should use the class name like this

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('input.addCheck').prop('checked',true);
});
```

Try Using this a  [live demo](http://jsfiddle.net/mmzf2c2f/)

Comment: answer is not relevant to the question.

Comment: yet the answer is entirely helpful to others who look for similar things, but not the exact OP question.

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```
$("input:checkbox").hasClass("myClass");
```

Answer (score 3):

Just in case any dummies like me tried the suggestions here with a button and found nothing worked, you probably want this:

```
$(':button.myclass')
```

Answer (score 1):

Another way:

```
$("input[class*='myClass']")
```