# Jquery - Radio button validation for multidemsional array

Tags: jquery, arrays, validation, multidimensional-array, radio-button

I am trying to add validation to a multidimensional radio buttons, but I am confused on how to add validation on this. Below is the image of the radio buttons

**On submit, I need to validate the radio buttons.** The radio buttons are added dynamically using loop and I tried vailidating but this is not working. I took some help from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41628897/validate-multidimensional-array-using-jquery-validate-plugin)

**PROBLEM**

```
<form id="quiz-new" method="POST" action="php/updatequiz.php" runat="server" enctype=multipart/form-data>
   <div class="txt-box">
     <input type="text" name="quiz[1][ques_title]">
     <input type="file" placeholder="Add Media" name="quiz[1][ques_image]" class="quiz-img-preview">
     <input type="radio" name="quiz[1][is_right]" value="392">
     <input type="radio" name="quiz[1][is_right]" value="393">
     <input type="radio" name="quiz[1][is_right]" value="394">
     <input type="radio" name="quiz[1][is_right]" value="395">
   </div>
   <div class="txt-box">
     <input type="text" name="quiz[2][ques_title]">
     <input type="file" placeholder="Add Media" name="quiz[2][ques_image]" class="quiz-img-preview">
     <input type="radio" name="quiz[2][is_right]" value="396">
     <input type="radio" name="quiz[2][is_right]" value="397">
     <input type="radio" name="quiz[2][is_right]" value="398">
     <input type="radio" name="quiz[2][is_right]" value="399">
   </div>
  <input type="submit" value="Create Quiz" class="create-quiz">
</form>
```

**FOOTER**

```
$('#quiz-new').validate();

var ques_title = $('input[name^="quiz"]');

ques_title.filter('input[name$="[ques_title]"]').each(function() {
    $(this).rules("add", {
        required: true,
        messages: {
            required: "Title is Mandatory"
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: **PROBLEM** section contains your code, you din't say what is the real problem?

Comment: Problem is how to add validation, as the **name** attribute is generated dynamically so I cannot say
 if (!$('input[name=quiz[]]:checked').val() ) @Mr.x

Comment: You could use a class to access the inputs instead of names. Like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1065944/9038475).

Comment: But as it is dynamically generated, so there will be many radio buttons with the same class @Geshode

Comment: Well, you try to add the validation to all radiobuttons, right? Then it shouldn't be a problem, that they all have the same class. Otherwise you have to give more details and context.

Comment: @Geshode, I have updated the question. I hope this helps

Comment: I really would try to make the four radio buttons belonging to each question uniquely recognizable through a class, name or id. Is there no way to achieve that in your plan?

Comment: Yes I can do that. I will add different classes for the group of radio buttons, but still how will I add validation for different classes ? @Geshode

Comment: You access the classes the same way you have done before with the name and then use the value for validation any way you want to. I assume, you know what and how you want to validate.

Comment: I have added validation, but it is not working for multidimensional arrays. @Geshode